# How to hide powershell welcome prompt

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I want to hide this welcome message i.e. `Loading personal and system profiles` & `Macbook Pro@DESKTOP-3UUQS2V`

All I want to only see is this `~` icon and respective directory. How would I do that in PowerShell?

[image]

Comment: ````-NoLogo````

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053189/how-do-i-disable-personal-and-system-profiles-loading-time-message-on-powershell

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053189/how-do-i-disable-personal-and-system-profiles-loading-time-message-on-powershell